# Java run without jar

Tags: java, jar

I wonder if it's possible to run a program without packaging it into a jar.

For instance we have this:

```
-AppRoot
    Main.class
    -Misc
        Math.class
        OtherTools.class
    -YetAnotherFolder
        UsefulFunctions.class
```

Is this possible? The main method should be executed from command line or similar.

Comment: Probably. Just compile everything using `javac`, then run the main class using `java`.

Comment: @RedRoboHood But how may I load the other classes?

Comment: They should be loaded automatically as long as your code doesn't have any problems and they're all compiled properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the most trivial Hello World will cover this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run this way from the AppRoot directory

```
javac -cp Misc/*:YetAnotherFolder/* Main.java //To compile

java -cp Misc/*:YetAnotherFolder/* Main // To run
```

Below is some documentation

```
  -classpath classpath
   -cp classpath
          Specifies a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search  for  class  files.   Class
          path  entries  are separated by colons (:). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the
          CLASSPATH environment variable.

          If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the user class path consists of the cur-
          rent directory (.).
```

Comment: If you are in the folder already in the terminal, you can just do: `javac <filename>.java` and then to run it you can do `java <filename>`

Answer (score 1):

Add all (sub-)directories containing class files to classpath and use the class with the `main` method as argument of the java executable.

The directory structure is your package structure.

`java -cp ./:./AppRoot:./AppRoot/Misc:./AppRoot/YetAnotherFolder AppRoot.Main`

This should work if all dependencies are resolved and on the classpath.